# CDI Injection of a pojo on JAX-RS class is throwing an exception

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi, ejb-3.1

I have a simple POJO class called MyService.java:

```
@RequestScoped
public class MyService {   
    public String helloWorld(){
        return "hello world!";
    }
}
```

I have a JAX-RS class where I want to Inject my POJO using CDI:

```
@Path("service")
public class RestfulService {
    public static AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
    @EJB
    MyEJB ejb;// The EJb injection works!
    @Inject 
    MyService service; // CDI injection does NOT work!

    @GET
    @Path("counter")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getTotal() {
        return  "Number of hits: " + counter.incrementAndGet();       
    }
}
```

Here is the exception thrown:

```
g.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=MyService,parent=RestfulService,qualifiers={},position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,1492861225)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:74)
```

The files `beans.xml`is present and the discovery-mode is set to `annotated`.

Any help please? Seems a basic example to me.

Comment: Is the beans.xml present in the WEB-INF folder ? CDI injection has not kicked in since it seems as if HK2 is still in charge of the injection

Comment: can you show server logs. do they mention weld being deployed?